# How to join consecutive int elements in a array in JS

Tags: javascript

I have the following array:

```
 my_array_tmp = [6,8,"=","A",1,0,"-"]
```

and I'd need to get the following array:

```
my_array = [68, "=", "A", 10, "-"]
```

I did research the solution in google but with no luck.

I'm a newby in JS.

Thank you for any help you can provide

Comment: What about strings that are numbers like `[ "6", 8 ]`? Should the result be `[ 68 ]`, `[ "68" ]` or `[ "6", 8 ]`?

Comment: it can't happen, in my code numbers can't be strings

Comment: I see I've got downvotes.. what's wrong? Is because the title is not exhaustive?

Comment: It's because you have to [show us what you have tried to solve the problem yourself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260828/do-we-need-a-close-reason-for-zero-effort-questions). BTW, I didn't downvote you.

Comment: ah okay, I did try but I could not find anyone having the same problem. Maybe I did not use the correct keywords.. I'll try harder next time.

Comment: You didn't show what you've tried.  No effort has been shown on your part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join and split with a regex and then filter out `undefined` and empty string

```
my_array_tmp = [6,8,"=","A",1,0,"-"];

result = my_array_tmp.join('').split(/([^0-9])|([])/).filter(x => !!x);
```

Comment: 1. This always produces array of strings, the numbers will be joined but will not be numbers any more. 2. There is a problem if one of the strings contains a number, for example `[6,8,"=","A1",1,0,"-"]` -> `[ "68", "=", "A", "110", "-" ]`  the `A` is not separated from the rest of the string. The `1` from the string is combined with the numbers following it.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate and check if they're numbers.  Accumulate pow10 sum of sequence of numbers.

reduce version:

```js
my_array_tmp = [6,8,"=","A",1,0,"-",1,'1']

res = []
res.push(my_array_tmp.reduce((l,x)=>
  typeof l==='number' && typeof x === 'number' ?
    l*10 + x :
    res.push(l) && x))

console.log(res)
```

simple for-of loop

```js
my_array_tmp = [6,8,"=","A",1,0,"-",1]

res = [], stack = 0, flag = false
for(const x of my_array_tmp)
  if(typeof x === 'number') {
    stack = stack*10 + x
    flag = true
  }
  else if(flag) {
    res.push(stack,x)
    stack = 0
    flag = false
  }
  else res.push(x)
if(flag) res.push(stack)


console.log(res)
```